# Show that the subgroup of all rotations in a dihedral group is a maximal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Show that the subgroup of all rotations in a dihedral group is a maximal subgroup.

Take $D_{2n} = \{1, \ r, \ r^2, \ ..., \ r^{n-1}, \ s, \ sr, \ sr^2, \ ..., \ sr^{n-1} \}$. Suppose $A= \langle r \rangle$ is
                not a maximal subgroup such that there exists a proper subgroup $B$ such that 
                $A \subset B \subset D_{2n}$. Then, there exists $x \in B$ such that $x \in \{s, sr, \ sr^2, \ ..., \ sr^{n-1} \}$. 
                If $x = s$, then $B=  D_{2n}$ since $D_{2n} = \langle r, \ s \rangle$. Contradiction.
                If $x = sr^i$ for some $i \in \{1, \ 2, \ ... \ n-1\}$, since $r^{-j} \in A \subset B$, $sr^jr^{-j}=s \in B$. 
                Then, $B=D_{2n}$. Contradiction.
                Hence, the subgroup of all rotations in a dihedral group
                is a maximal subgroup.

Is my reasoning correct? I am new to the field and am struggling...

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: As Thad Janisse notes, your proof is great. However, do you know of Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: Since $[D_{2n}: \langle r\rangle] = 2$, if $\langle r\rangle \subset B \subset  D_{2n}$ it follows that $1 < [D:B] < 2$; contradiction, as $[D:B]$ must be an integer. This is what Alex is referring to.